# Angular 8 with Server Side Rendering

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-universal

I migrated my app from an angular 5 to angular 8 and added server side rendering feature .While i am staring the SSR server via terminal app started with out any errors ,but in browser i am getting the below error while running the application.I searched from Google and applied some fixes,nothing is worked.

**Error: This method is not implemented in DominoAdapter: getCookie
    at _notImplemented**

Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular universal, you cannot just access the cookies the way you would in the navigator.

To be able to get cookies, you need to pass the Request and response object from your nodeJs server to your angular app, using providers.

To make things easier, you could use the [ngx-cookie](https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie) lib, which support angular universal

Comment: Thanks David ,Let me try